# Restricting gnuplot data in palette and interpolating between points (3D)

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot, interpolation

I have a dataset with 4 columns: x,y,z,c, and the following gnuplot script to plot the data:

```
set pm3d interpolate 3,3,3

set palette defined  ( 0 "purple", 1 "blue" , 2 "cyan" , 3 "green" ,4 "orange",5 "red",6 "brown",7 "black",8 "grey" )
 
show palette gradient
sp 'datasets' u 1:2:3:4 palette lt 7 not
```

It makes a very nice plot, all data are small points, I can rotate around...etc.

My questions would be, how can I restrict the plotting to let's say colors 0 and 2 (without modifying the datafile).

The secondary question is, how could I interpolate the colors between data points?

Comment: I don't clearly understand: do you want to plot only that data points which have the color 0 or 2 (i.e. filtering the datafile)?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason a word was missing, I corrected my question!

Comment: How exactly does your input data look like? Ok, `x,y,z,c`, but is `c` a color code or a number between `0` and `1`? I assume `c` is independent of `z`, correct? Could you please provide some minimal test data?

Comment: x, y, z is ranging between -10 and 10, so its a 10x10x10 cube (so its a coordinate). While c is a color code for the data points (forming extended continuous regions) of this cube (coming from some model)


-1 1 2 0
-1 1 3 0
-1 1 4 0
-1 1 5 0
4 10 2 1
5 10 2 1
6 10 2 1
7 10 2 2
8 10 2 2
9 10 2 2
-2 3 7 3
-2 4 7 3
-2 5 7 3
-2 6 7 3
-2 7 7 4

so optimally i want to color a 3D cube interior based on my "grid", which is not regular... and the 4th column represents the color of that particular coordinate:

Answer (score 1):

1. To filter the data points, you can use the condition form `?:` for    one of your column e.g.:

   ```
   using 1:2:(($4==0 || $4==2)?$3:1/0):4
   ```
2. To keep the color scale correct, you have to fix the `cbrange`:

   ```
   set cbrange [0:8]
   ```
3. For interpolation: the `set pm3d interpolate` has only two    arguments. (0,0 is for automatic).

Therefore, my solution:

```
set pm3d interpolate 0,0

set palette defined  ( 0 "purple", 1 "blue" , 2 "cyan" , 3 "green" ,4 "orange",5 "red",6 "brown",7 "black",8 "grey" )

# First image: all data
splot '009_d.dat' u 1:2:3:4 palette lt 7 notitle

# Second image: restricted data with wrong colors
splot '009_d.dat' u 1:2:(($4==0 || $4==2)?$3:1/0):4 palette lt 7 notitle

set cbrange [0:8]

# Third image: restricted data with correct colors
splot '009_d.dat' u 1:2:(($4==0 || $4==2)?$3:1/0):4 palette lt 7 notitle

# Fourth image: interpolated splot
splot '009_d.dat' u 1:2:3:4 palette lt 7 notitle w pm3d
```

[image: First image: all data]
[image: Second image: restricted data with wrong colors]

[image: Third image: restricted data with correct colors]
[image: Fourth image: interpolated splot]

Comment: The beautiful soliton of the restriction, I didn't know about this! However, the last line produces an empty plot for some reason

gnuplot> rep
Warning: Single isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot.
    Hint: Missing blank lines in the data file? See 'help pm3d' and FAQ.
         all scans empty

Comment: Sady, `pm3d` needs specific format of data. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048960)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not really the same, as that is a 3D plot, where the third column is a color/ height of the plot. My data is a 3D dataset with the 4th column being the color.

Comment: The 4th column doesn't matter: as you can see on my 4th figure, I have used x:y:z:c. The point is that if you want to use `pm3d` (with or without interpolation) surface plot, you have to arrange your data by x and y. This grid indicates the interpolation lines.

Comment: That is the difference, it's not a surface plot that I want to achieve, My data cannot be represented on a 2D slice, because it is 3D data. I would like to interpolate in 3D regions, to have "shaded volumes"

Comment: Then, `pm3d` is not your friend. Try to search for `voxel`.